# Re-assemble assembly code from objdump

Tags: assembly, binary, x86, intel

I have a binary file that I first disassembled with objdump like this:

```
objdump -Mintel -d mybinary
```

The result looks like this (I only put a part of it, the idea is that you see how it looks):

```
patchme:     format de fichier elf64-x86-64

Déassemblage de la section .init :

00000000004003e0 <_init>:
  4003e0:   48 83 ec 08             sub    rsp,0x8
  4003e4:   48 8b 05 0d 0c 20 00    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x200c0d]        # 600ff8 <_DYNAMIC+0x1d0>
  4003eb:   48 85 c0                test   rax,rax
  4003ee:   74 05                   je     4003f5 <_init+0x15>
  4003f0:   e8 3b 00 00 00          call   400430 <__gmon_start__@plt>
  4003f5:   48 83 c4 08             add    rsp,0x8
  4003f9:   c3                      ret
```

I modified the assembly code (and the associated hex values). I would like to know if there is an easy way to re-assemble this code to binary? Like a command which does it.

Thank you!

PS: I know I could convert every hex to binary and concatenate them... But it's kind of a lot of work :-p

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hex editor or patch tool to apply your changes to the original binary (you can pass the `--file-offset` argument to objdump to have it tell you the actual file location of the offsets you are modifying).

Of course, you can always just strip out the address and hex and then use the assembler of your choice to re-assemble the code, but then you still have the question of how to patch it into the original binary (which presumably contains more than just the section you showed above).